# Hibernate: index descriptor not valid on SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have two tables, documents and revisions. One document may have many revisions, and one revision has one and only one document. When I try to retrieve versions from a document I get an exception (see full stack trace attached).

If I retrieve versions it works, and I can get it's related document. The problem is on documents getting the set of revisions.

Tried on MySQL and works fine. Thanks for your help, see all relevant information attached:

**Database configuration**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DOCUMENTS](
    [ID_DOCUMENT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](255) NULL)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VERSIONS](
    [ID_VERSION] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_DOCUMENT] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Hibernate configuration files**

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:odbc:documental</property
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="mappings/Document.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="mappings/Version.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Document.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entities.Document" table="DOCUMENTS">
        <id name="idDocument" type="java.lang.Integer" column="ID_DOCUMENT">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <set name="versions" table="VERSIONS" inverse="true">
            <key column="ID_DOCUMENT" />
            <one-to-many class="entities.Version" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Version.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entities.Version" table="VERSIONS">
        <id name="idVersion" type="java.lang.Integer" column="ID_VERSION">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="document" class="entities.Document" fetch="select">
            <column name="ID_DOCUMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Java classes**

Document.java

```
public class Document implements Serializable {
    private java.lang.Integer idDocument;
    private Set<Version> versions;

    public Document(){}

    //Autogenerated getters and setters
}
```

Version.java

```
public class Version implements Serializable {
    private java.lang.Integer idVersion;
    private Document document;

    public Version(){}

    //Autogenerated getters and setters
}
```

**Full stack trace**

```
>Exception occurred in target VM: could not initialize a collection: [entities.Document.versions#1] 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection: [entities.Document.versions#1]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2001)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:60)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:344)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:109)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:139)
at servlets.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:33)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1805)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Índice descriptor no válido
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataInteger(JdbcOdbc.java:3810)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataInteger(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5637)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:582)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:600)
at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:28)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readKey(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:734)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:975)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:646)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:591)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1994)
... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing driver to jDTS (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).